# thumbnail image creation script problem

Tags: php, image

```
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'users/158/images/thumbs/1308420484.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/cham1992/public_html/uploadimg.php on line 99

Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open 'users/158/images/thumbs/small_thumbs/1308420484.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /home/cham1992/public_html/uploadimg.php on line 99
```

i got this error when creating thumbnails for original image using php.what's the solution for this.

users folder permissions=0777

Comment: Check if the folder exists and if the path the folder is in is relative to the path of the executing script. If you're not sure use absolute path's.

Comment: all paths are correct and original image 1308420484.jpg was uploaded successfully to server without thumbs

Comment: are the thumbs and small_thumbs folder already created or are you expecting imagejpeg() to do that? imagejpeg propably won't so you might consider creating those dir's before saving thumbs to them.

Comment: folders are already created when user registered

Comment: You must have the filenames wrong. Check again.

Comment: That path looks relative, you should double check.  Re-stating the obvious of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`is_writable`](http://php.net/is_writable). Additionally you can use `file_exists` to check if the file exists. The file may exist but there may be a reason PHP can't access it.

Comment: Check the permissions I guess. What about `file_exists`?

Comment: it shows file does not exists , but actually file does exists